# How to give path to a file within a package?

Tags: python, import, module, package

I have a Python package structure of which is :

```
.
├── ACC
│   └── test.py
├── API
│   ├── Dep
│   │   └── hello.py
│   ├── hello2.py
│   └── test.txt
├── hello1.py
└── __init__.py
```

In code hello2.py,hello.py and test.py,I want to access test.txt and it works when I run code from API as directory and give relative path in but it fails when I import this package in some other working directory.

One way is to give the absolute path.I tried this way and it's working but need to change path whenever location of folders changes.

**QUESTION:** Is there any way so that I can use relative path in this scenario or any other better way?